# React function in displaying returned value not working

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display calculated values from a function called renderAnalysis - all which works until the bottom of the function where I am trying to return a div with the values that are found. However, this isn't displaying (all values are returned though in the console when I test it out) and was wondering what I need to adjust to prevent the values I can show in the console? I think I'm doing a render call wrong or something... I've added the code for reference. Thank you!

```
renderAnalysis = () => {
        let reactions = this.state.reactions;
        let foods = Object.keys(reactions);
        foods.map((food) => {
            let reactionDescriptions = reactions[food];
            let reactionDescriptionKeys = Object.keys(reactionDescriptions);

            let responseKey = Object.keys(reactionDescriptions);

            responseKey.map((singleDescription) => {
                let value = reactionDescriptions[singleDescription];

                // RETURN VALUE NOT SHOWING
                return <div> {(food, singleDescription, value)} </div>;
            });
        });
    };
```

Further information: There is a toggle I made in state that if someone clicks a button it triggers this function. Basically

```
        <button onClick={this.displayRenderAnalysisToggle}>
            Render Analysis
        </button>{" "}
        <br />
        {this.state.displayRenderAnalysisToggle ? this.renderAnalysis() : null}
    </div>
```

Comment: Your `map` functions do not return anything. This leads to `renderAnalysis` returning `undefined`.

Comment: Just `return foods.map` and then `return responseKey.map`.

Comment: Could I get further details on what to do? I'm still learning a lot about React and I really appreciate it

Comment: @Candace You have to return `JSX` from `renderAnalysis` function for rendering the divs you have created. That would be done when you `return responseKey.map` and  then `return foods.map`.

Comment: The return you have inside the map does not cascade down as a return from the next wrapping function. You have to say "return the result of the map, then return the result of the outer map as the return of the full function". To do that you add returns at the previous comment explains

Comment: Oh, awesome. Thank you so much! I really appreciate it